# How to select column in a table

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors

I get tables, without any css attributes, some columns are optional.

```
<TABLE>
<TR>
    <TH>name A(optional)</TH>
    <TH>name B</TH>
    <TH>name C</TH>
</TR>
<TR>
    <TD>name 1A(optional)</TD>
    <TD>name 1B</TD>
    <TD>name 1C</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
    <TD>name 2A(optional)</TD>
    <TD>name 2B</TD>
    <TD>name 2C</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
```

I need to select column with name "name B", but this collumn is not always second!
So I need to select it according to name.

In the worst-case scenario according to id attribute in header

```
<TH id="nameB">name B</TH>
```

Comment: Do you mean row or column? Those with name "name2" are in a row.

Comment: There is no CSS selector for matching an element based on its contents.

Comment: sorry about mistakes, more info added.

Answer (score 3):

You can look into the cell contents like this:

```
var ths = document.getElementsByTagName('th');
var tds = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
var column = [];
for (var i=0; i<ths.length; i++) {
    if (ths[i].innerHTML.match(/name \d*B/)) {
       column.push(ths[i]);
    }
}
for (var i=0; i<tds.length; i++) {
    if (tds[i].innerHTML.match(/name \d*B/)) {
       column.push(tds[i]);
    }
}
console.log(column);
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VZVhR/1/).

Or simply match the column head and get the rest of the elements:

```
var ths = document.getElementsByTagName('th');
var trs = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
var column = [];
for (var i=0; i<ths.length; i++) {
    if (ths[i].innerHTML.indexOf('name B') !== -1) {
        var id = i;
        break;
    }
}
for (var i=0; i<trs.length; i++) {
    column.push(trs[i].children[id]);
}
console.log(column);
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VZVhR/2/).

Answer (score 1):

If this is a table that you are designing yourself, you might be able to make progress by learning about formatting table columns as described in:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#columns

see also:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.4.2

This is a more advanced topic not often mentioned in CSS design books, worth a look.

Comment: its not, its a table i get as an export from machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want extreme simple solution without any burden of css you can just apply same class to all elements you want to select like this,

```
<TABLE>
    <TR>
        <TH>name A(optional)</TH>
        <TH class="red">name B</TH>
        <TH>name C</TH>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD>name 1A(optional)</TD>
        <TD class="red">name 1B</TD>
        <TD>name 1C</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD>name 2A(optional)</TD>
        <TD class="red">name 2B</TD>
        <TD>name 2C</TD>
    </TR>
</TABLE>
```

And then style as you want,

```
.red {
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: Is there a solution only with classes within <TH> elements?

Answer (score 0):

With this function you can get the column element passing the column index:

```
/**
* 
* @param {Object} table: the table dom selector 
* @param {indexColumn} number: start count with 0 
* @returns Array with the column element selected by index column
*/
function getColumnElementsByIndexColumn(table, indexColumn) {
    const tableRows = table.querySelectorAll("tr");
    let columnElements = [];

    for (row of tableRows) {
        let columnElement = row.children[indexColumn];
        columnElements.push(columnElement);
    }

    return columnElements;
}
```

**Question case, the column index is 1 that represents the second column):**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>name A(optional)</th>
        <th>name B</th>
        <th>name C</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>name 1A(optional)</td>
        <td>name 1B</td>
        <td>name 1C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>name 2A(optional)</td>
        <td>name 2B</td>
        <td>name 2C</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script>
    const table = document.querySelector("table");
    let secondColumnELements = getColumnElementsByIndexColumn(table, 1);
    console.log(secondColumnELements[0].innerText); // name B
    console.log(secondColumnELements[1].innerText); // name 1B
    console.log(secondColumnELements[2].innerText); // name 2B
</script>
```

Now, you can apply a css class in this elements using Javascript

Answer (score 0):

In two lines of JavaScript you can also do:

```js
var idx = document.querySelector('tr').innerText.split('\t').indexOf('name B')+1;
var colArr = [...document.querySelectorAll('th:nth-child('+idx+'),td:nth-child('+idx+')')].forEach(el => el.classList.add('gotcha'))
```

```css
td,th
{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.gotcha
{
  background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
    <th>name A</th>
    <th>name B</th>
    <th>name C</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>name 1A(optional)</td>
    <td>name 1B</td>
    <td>name 1C</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>name 2A(optional)</td>
    <td>name 2B</td>
    <td>name 2C</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

### Explication:

In the 1st row of the JavaScript code, the split() function creates an array from the first row th elements separating them by the tabulation \t char and gets the index at which the th innerText string of your interest is at, if any, else returns -1.

Because the JavaScript arrays are 0 based but the table columns in css are 1 based, we add +1 to the idx to get the correct column index

In the 2nd row of the JavaScript code, querySelectorAll selects the th and td elements at the idx cell index returning an HTML node list or collection that we transform into an array like object with the help of the spread syntax **[...object]** so the forEach method can be used.

So we pass to the forEach an arrow function and with that code we add a class to all cells of the same column to better show the result of the selection.
Of cours the same code works if the string you are looking for is in any th innerText.

While if the code doesn't find any th with *name B*, indexOf returns -1 and nothing gets formatted because the idx will be 0 and the querySelectorAll will return an empty NodeList because the idx value will be out of cells index range. As a result nothing will be selected nor formatted in yellow.

You can just move the *name B* string to another th element or remove it completely to see the relative result.